# LEFT JOIN in Django ORM (left join bettwen two tables and stock the result in a third table)

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following models:

```
class Somme_Quantity_In_T(models.Model):
    Family_Label = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Site = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    Product = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    Vendor = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Produit(models.Model):
    Taux = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    Famille = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
    NIP = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    NGS = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True)

class Produit_a_ajouter(models.Model):
    Family_Label = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Site = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    Product = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    Vendor = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I want to query for this following query:

```
SELECT Somme_Quantity_In_T.* 
FROM Somme_Quantity_In_T
LEFT JOIN Produit
ON Somme_Quantity_In_T.product = Produit.NIP 
AND Somme_Quantity_In_T.Family_Label = Produit.Famille
WHERE Produit.NIP is null
```

And I want to stock the result of this query in **Produit_a_ajouter** table

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please expand on what you've tried and where you get stuck? Please take a moment to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You don't join in Django. Django joins for you. Well, you have to define relationships for your models first.

Comment: can you please give me the example of the code @KlausD.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial02/